# "What is fun for you?" "It is to play baseball."

Tags: infinitives, infinitive-vs-gerund

I'm an ESL teacher, and I'm having a difficult time deciding if these sentences are grammatically correct or natural:

1. A: "What is fun for you?"
   B: "It is to play baseball."
2. A: "What is the important thing to you?"
   B: "It is to play baseball."

I think the second one is more natural, but are they both grammatically correct? I would naturally use "playing" in both scenarios, so I'd gladly accept any opinions!

Comment: So your problem is "to play baseball" vs "playing baseball", right?

Answer (score 1):

Neither your questions, nor your answers, sound idiomatic.

The most natural would be:

> Q. What do you do for fun?
> A. I play baseball.

Your questions just don't sound natural, and the replies are unnecessarily formal, especially for a discussion about fun and baseball.

Answer (score -1):

In both case A.'s I would say no they do not sound natural but I am English not American. I have played rounders but never baseball.

In both cases I would have thought a word indicating the amount of fun/pleasure would normally be added to the sentence. Also the topic is huge so we could be more specific.

A: "What game do you find most fun?" B: "Is it baseball?"

A: "What do you like most?" B: "Is it playing baseball?"

A: "Is playing baseball important to you?"